# which plugin in VIM is responsible for datetime and "opened tab" information at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: r, vim

I am trying to create an R IDE under Linux Mint environment following the instruction (in Chinese) [here](http://equation85.github.com/blog/vim-working-env/).

I installed `NERDTree` and `vim-r-plugin` as instructed, and skipped the `vcscommand` and `fuzzyfinder` for the moment.

The page shows the output of the IDE:

[image]

It's almost OK for me, but I wonder why I cannot see the last line as shown in the output, the line with datetime and names of the tabs open. How can I show this line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that's actually from [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen).

It appears that that image is showing a screen session with the current screen window split into two panes. The top pane contains vim which is itself split into 3 vim windows, and the bottom pane is running what I'm assuming is an R interpreter. The last line of the image is the screen status line.

It's possible that [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) is actually being used in place of screen.

Comment: @romainl I also think that it looks more like `tmux` than `screen`, but the linked page doesn't have any references to `tmux`.